# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn generado desde código

Tags: wpf

Estoy generando una columna en formato combo desde código que se incluye en un datagridview editable asociado a un DataTable.

Al situarme en la celda, aparece el combo con los valores, pero no consigo que se muestre el SelectedValue en la celda. De hecho en la carga inicial de datos esa celda ya no muestra el valor de la lista de datos ( recibo los valores, 0,1,o 2 en la tabla de datos), y supongo que de alguna manera no he sabido crear el binding necesario.

Agradecería cualquier aportación para desencallar el tema.

```
    protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
           if ( e.PropertyName == "combocolumn") {
                    var cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                    cb.Header = "Columna Combo";
                    cb.Visibility =  Visibility.Visible;
                    cb.IsReadOnly = false;
                    cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Descripcion";
                    cb.SelectedValuePath = "Codigo";
                    cb.ItemsSource = Datos;
                    
                    e.Column = cb;
                    
                  }
            
            
            base.OnAutoGeneratingColumn(e);
        }

// ===> datos ...
 public class DatosCombo
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        
    }


 private List<DatosCombo> Datos= new List<DatosCombo>()
        {
            new DatosCombo() { Codigo = 0,Descripcion="Dato1"},
            new DatosCombo() { Codigo = 1,Descripcion="Dato2"},
            new DatosCombo() { Codigo = 2,Descripcion="Dato3"}
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si es util para más gente, ya solucioné el problema agregando:

```
 cb.SelectedValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("DatosCombo");
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).